# Alamofire conflict with SugarRecord?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, alamofire

In my project I download some data using Alamofire, the I need to save them with CoreData, using SugarRecord, but I get a strange error when I fetch my entities, like this:

```
var albums: [CDAlbum]

        do {

            albums = try! db.fetch(Request<CDAlbum>())

        } catch {
            // TODO: handle errors as appropriate
            print("ERROR FETCHING ALBUMs")
        }
```

I get a red dot that say "Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Request'"

Now, if I click on "Request", Xcode redirect me to Alamofire folder>Request.swift, but I need the method from SugarRecord>CoreData>NSManagedObjectContext.swift called

```
public func fetch<T: Entity>(request: Request<T>) throws -> [T] {}
```

It seems that Xcode confuse the two methods. How could I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fix this disambiguation adding the name module `SugarRecord.`

```
albums = try! db.fetch(SugarRecord.Request<CDAlbum>())
```

Comment: Exactly. I opened an issue on the repository to rename Request by FetchRequest and avoid having to specify the namespace every time.

Comment: Here's the issue reference: https://github.com/carambalabs/SugarRecord/issues/280

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue downloading Alamofire (before was installed by cocoapods) and renaming the Request class to Requeste.